# Can I get the uptime check percentage for a particular uptime check via stackdriver monitoring api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have uptime checks configured for my instances in google cloud stackdriver. Now I need to programatically check the uptime percentage through that uptime check. Is there any api available for the same ?

I checked the documentation and didn't find any api to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a couple of metrics of interest:

- monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed - True if check passed
- monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/request_latency - Latency in msecs

see also:  [Creating Uptime Charts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/uptime-charts)

Once can use these metrics for charts and alerts.  In addition, since all metric data is retrievable as time-series information using APIs (at least REST APIs) then you can periodically retrieve the data and perform calculations upon it.

Also distinguish this from the metric called compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime which is how long a VM has been running.

Comment: Do you have some additional information?  I can not understand how to retrieve all metric data from API. Do you have any example or link with an example? Everting have sense but I can not fully understand how to do that.